# How can I change the system language without changing shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, language

I would like to change the OS X system language on one Mac from English to French. If I do that, all standard-shortcuts also change.
We use the Dvorak keyboard layout on all Macs.

**Example:**
In Preview, basically all shortcuts seem to by language-dependent.
For example, View → Thumbnails which is ALT+CMD+1 will be something entirely different.

The fact that all shortcuts are changed as well makes the system almost unusable (efficiently), esp. if you got to change between different-language macs frequently.

How can I change the system language without changing shortcuts?

Comment: Could you explain why one user would need to frequently change the system language on their Mac?  Perhaps there is an easier way to accomplish the purpose for which this is being done.  Or do users have to switch between Mac's whose system language they cannot change?

Comment: Hello Tom, yep it is the latter!